# Python Animating NetCDF Array in Multiple directories and files for Radar Rainfall

Tags: python, animation, directory, subdirectory, netcdf

Next part the Bureau of Meteorology Puzzle: I have a directory structure

```
> `-- 2012/
>     |           |-- 02/
>     |           |   |-- 27/
>     |           |   |-- 28/
>     |           |   `-- 29/ 
>     |           `-- 03/
>     |               |-- 01/
>     |               |-- 02/ 
>     |               |-- 03/
>     |               |-- 04/ 
>     |               `-- 05/
```

containing netcdf files of radar rainfall in 10 minute time slices, for an 8 day storm event. I want to be able to animate the RADAR Loop of the event, and also produce a final plot of the Total Accumulated Rainfall.

I have no Idea how to start? I need to read directories & files, and create an Array I imagine?
The files are all zipped up here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15223371/2012.zip

Would dearly appreciate any pointers on how to start the code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok after quite a bit of searching I am well on my way.... However can't figure out how to ANIMATE .... and as yet create a Sum ( Accumulation) of all the Arrays?

```
   import os
import sys
import glob
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import netcdf
import pylab as pl
from easygui import *
import fnmatch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



print 'START...'
cur_dir= os.getcwd()
top_dir = os.path.dirname(cur_dir)
print cur_dir
print top_dir
print 'Present Directory Open...'
title = "Select Directory to Read Multiple rainfall .nc files"
msg = "This is a test of the diropenbox.\n\nPick the directory that you wish to open."
d = diropenbox(msg, title)
fromdir = d
rootPath = fromdir
pattern = '*.nc'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        #print( os.path.join(root, filename))
        print filename
        # Now read NetCDF file and Plot the Radar Rainfall Array
        """
        data = NetCDFFile(filename, netcdf_mode_r)
        print 'VARIABLES:'
        print data.variables        
        """

        data = netcdf.NetCDFFile(os.path.join(root, filename), 'r')
        #print 'VARIABLES:'
        #print data.variables
        try:
            precip = data.variables['precipitation'].data
            x = data.variables['x_loc'].data
            y = data.variables['y_loc'].data
        except:
            precip = data.variables['precip'].data
            x = data.variables['x_loc'].data
            y = data.variables['y_loc'].data
        #raw_input('hold..')
        #print x
        plt.title('RADAR RAINFALL'+filename, size=20)
        plt.imshow(precip, origin='lower', interpolation='bicubic',extent=(x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()))
        plt.colorbar()
        plt.show()
```

Comment: How can I animate the Arrays ??

Comment: Ok.... by using plt.savefig('RADAR RAINFALL'+filename[-16:-3]+'.jpg',format='jpg'), I am able to save images and produce an animation external to Python. (Is there a way to do it without creating 1000's of images though) ???